# Konvajs Grayscale turn off

Tags: filter, grayscale, konvajs

I am using Konvajs filters to give the user the ability to change brightness, contrast and grayscale of the image.
As per the KonvaJs examples I am using input sliders which works great.
For Brightness and Contrast I am using:

```
image.filters([Konva.Filters.Brighten, Konva.Filters.Contrast]);
```

But for Grayscale I am using input slider as an on/off switch and the following filter:

```
image.filters([Konva.Filters.Grayscale]);
```

So when the users sets the Grayscale switch to "on" I can invoke the Grayscale filter.
But if the user then switches Grayscale to "off" there doesn't seem to be a way of cancelling this filter.

I have a workaround that involves cancelling ALL filters:

```
image.filters([]);
```

And then re-invoking the brightness and contrast filters to the value previously set.
Is there a way to simply cancel the Grayscale filter?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to remove the filter of a `Konva.Node` is to remove it from the `filters` property. So if you want to reset filters or enabled/disable them you should do something like this:

```js
const filters = [];

if (needBrighten) {
  filters.push(Konva.Filters.Brighten);
}
if (needContrast) {
  filters.push(Konva.Filters.Contrast);
}
if (needGrayscale) {
  filters.push(Konva.Filters.Grayscale);
}
node.filters(filters);
```

Variables like `needBrighten` you may need to detect from your inputs.